# Plot several columns of table with variable number of columns and display the legend accordingly

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I use this command to plot all values from the 1st column of Table "results" against  all values from the 2nd column:

```
ListLinePlot[{results[[All, {1, 2}]]}
```

Now, I would like to plot all columns two until some N (always against the first column). I tried (for N=3):

```
ListLinePlot[ArrayFlatten[Table[results[[All, {1, i}]], {i, 2, 3}]]
```

which does work. Is this the simplest solution? Further, how to display the legend for a general N, if for N=3 the relevant part of ListLinePlot looks like:

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[{"n=1", "n=2", "n=3"}, Right]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
results = Sort@RandomInteger[100, {20, 30}];
```

Columns `2`, `5` and `12` versus `1`:

```
ListLinePlot[results[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 5, 12},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Row[{"n = ", #}] & /@ {2, 5, 12}, Right]]
```

[image]

```
columns = {2, 3, 15, 20};
ListLinePlot[results[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ columns,
    PlotLegends -> Placed[Row[{"n = ", #}] & /@ columns, Right]]
```

[image]

Or, you can define a function that takes a list of columns to plot against column 1:

```
llp[cols_List] := ListLinePlot[results[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ cols, 
                  PlotLegends -> Placed[Row[{"n = ", #}] & /@ cols, Right]]
llp[{2, 3 , 15, 20}]
(* same picture *)
```